# Referencing Flashbuilder Views by their string name

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flashbuilder4

I have a TabbedViewNavigator application with a navigatory bar which opens view just fine.  In each view there is a ButtonBar that will open a new view related to the parent view. I have a single handler which decodes the name of the button and can build a string with the name of the view to be opened.  I am looking for some way of referencing the view from this string, in a similar fashion to `this["someName"]` or `getDefinitionByName("someName")`. In my code, 'this' refers to the current view and the views that I need to find are not child elements.  I don't know where `getDefinitionByName()` is looking, but it can't find the view either.

I have solved it temporarily with a switch statement, but this is not a good solution.  Is there a view collection; if so, who is the owner of the collection or am I not going about this in the correct way.

Thanks for reading this far.

Answer (score 0):

If the view is in a package/folder, you need to supply the full package to `getDefinitionByName`:

```
var viewClass : Class = getDefinitionByName("com.us.project.AwesomeView");

var view : DisplayObject = new viewClass();
```